# Calculate Median using Java Stream API

Tags: java

Is it possible to use the Java Stream API to find the median of a Collection of numeric values? I have a variable of type `List<Double>` which is unsorted.

The javadocs from JDK9 to 14 seem to indicate that `median()` is not a valid method for a `DoubleStream`.
Average, Minimum, Maximum, Count, and Sum are valid aggregation functions though.

Is `median()` not a valid method because it requires a sorted Collection prior to streaming?

This works fine with `average()` :

```java
   // Function to find average element from a List of Integers in Java 9 and above
   public static Double getAverageWithStream(List<Double> list) {
      OptionalDouble average = list.stream() // Stream<Double>
                                 .mapToDouble(v -> v) // DoubleStream
                                 .average(); // OptionalDouble

      // Print out a message about the 'average' variable's value
      // Note: ifPresentOrElse() was introduced in JDK9
      average.ifPresentOrElse(
         // message the value if one exists
         (value) -> {
            System.out.println("The average value is " + value);
         },
         // Alert the user that there is no value
         () -> {
            System.out.println("No average could be determined!");
         }
      ); // end ifPresentOrElse()

      return average.orElse(Double.NaN);
   } // end getAverageWithStream()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment left by @Robert Bain, my method would need to be changed in the following manner to support a median aggregation :

```java
   /**
    * Function to find median element from a List of Integers in Java 9 and above
    * @param list List<Double>
    * @return Double
    */
   public static Double getMedianWithStream(List<Double> list) {
      DoubleStream sortedNumbers = list.stream() // Stream<Double>
                                 .mapToDouble(v -> v) // DoubleStream
                                 .sorted(); // DoubleStream sorted

      OptionalDouble median = (
         list.size() % 2 == 0 ?
         sortedNumbers.skip((list.size() / 2) - 1)
                     .limit(2)
                     .average() :
         sortedNumbers.skip(list.size() / 2)
                     .findFirst()
      );

      // Print out a message about the 'average' variable's value
      // Note: ifPresentOrElse() was introduced in JDK9
      median.ifPresentOrElse(
         // message the value if one exists
         (value) -> {
            System.out.println("The median value is " + value);
         },
         // Alert the user that there is no value
         () -> {
            System.out.println("No median could be determined!");
         }
      ); // end ifPresentOrElse()

      return median.orElse(Double.NaN);
   } // end getAverageWithStream()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no median(), you would have to roll your own, though I think sorting will be required given the nature of it.

If you're going with the mathematical definition of the median (and not the mean), then you simply need to find the middle of your sorted list:

```
mylist.sort()
int median = mylist[list.size/2]
```

But you'll need to turn your stream into a list to do this which might not be what you want.